# FormArray with add/remove buttons activate in a strange order when pressing the enter key

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a simple reactive form where I add/remove a list of items using FormArray. Each list item has a Remove button assigned to it so I can remove the item from the list. There is also an Add button that I can use to add items in the list(as the source code shows below. [Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h7p8mj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html))

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";

interface Recipient {
  name: string;
  email: string;
}
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  form = this.fb.group({
    recipients: this.fb.array([])
  });
  recipient: Recipient = {
    name: "",
    email: ""
  };

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.recipients().push(
      this.newRecipientGroup({
        name: "test",
        email: "test email"
      })
    );
    this.recipients().push(
      this.newRecipientGroup({
        name: "test",
        email: "test email"
      })
    );
  }

  recipients() {
    return this.form.get("recipients") as FormArray;
  }

  newRecipientGroup(recipient: Recipient) {
    return this.fb.group({
      name: recipient.name,
      email: recipient.email
    });
  }
  addRecipient() {
    this.recipients().push(this.newRecipientGroup(this.recipient));
    this.recipient = {
      name: "",
      email: ""
    };
  }

  removeRecipient(i: number, recipient: FormGroup) {
    console.log("removeRecipient ->", i, recipient);
    this.recipients().removeAt(i);
  }
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">


    <table formArrayName="recipients">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let recipient of recipients().controls; let i = index;" [formGroupName]="i">
            <td>
                <input formControlName="name"  type="text">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input formControlName="email"  type="text">
            </td>
            <td>
                <button (click)="removeRecipient(i, recipient)">Remove
                                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input [(ngModel)]="recipient.name" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" placeholder="Name" type="text">
                    </td>
            <td>
                <input [(ngModel)]="recipient.email" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" placeholder="Email" type="text">
                    </td>
            <td>
                <button (click)="addRecipient()" >Add
                        </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

The problem is when I want to add a new list item using the enter key instead of clicking the Add button. Doing so, the `removeRecipient` method is called instead of the `addRecipient` method. If there are no items in the list, then the `addRecipient` method is called as expected

Why is this behaviour like so and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your code for "removeRecipient" functionality, you need to define the type of button. Within a form, a button acts like "Submit" by default, but if you define type of button like below, then it will not submit your form and will not call "removeRecipient" function on Enter key.

```
 <button (click)="removeRecipient(i, recipient)" type="button">Remove</button>
```

I tried in your given code, it worked for me.

Comment: you are right. Can't believe I missed this. Thank you